# Why does changing the height of the footline in beamer lead to the distortion of the title page image?

Tags: beamer

In Presentation Template Javeriana https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/presentation-template-javeriana/phkznvynkhvn, why does changing the height of the footline lead to the distortion of the title page image? More precisely, when I change the default setting ''ht=5mm,dp=3mm'' to ''ht=2.6mm,dp=0.7mm'' in beamerthemesintef.sty file, there is a missing corner in the title page (see the picture below). However, there is no problem with the default setting. How to fix this problem? [image: picture)].

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\textwidth,ht=5mm,dp=3mm,rightskip=1cm,leftskip=1cm]{footline}
  \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
  \ifstrempty{\@footlinepayoff}{}{%
    \usebeamerfont{footline}\hfill\@footlinepayoff
  }
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Looks like a white rectangle sticking out there. Probably from some frame. Just guessing though. Someone who knows beamer will tell for sure.

Comment: If you change the footline, the height of the text box changes and the title, which looks to be placed in the vertical centre, will be moved up/down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you reduce the height of the footline, the height of the text area will get bigger and the vertically centred title will move down.

To avoid it from obscuring the background image, you can set the background colour of the title to empty:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{
%amsfonts,amsmath,
oldgerm}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{verbatim}


\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usetheme{sintef}

\newcommand{\testcolor}[1]{\colorbox{#1}{\textcolor{#1}{test}}~\texttt{#1}}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\titlebackground*{assets/background}

\newcommand{\hrefcol}[2]{\textcolor{cyan}{\href{#1}{#2}}}

\title{Big data - Parte 2}

\author{\href{mailto:oscar.bustos@javeriana.edu.co}{Oscar Bustos}}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\textwidth,ht=2.6mm,dp=0.7mm,rightskip=1cm,leftskip=1cm]{footline}
  \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
  \ifstrempty{\@footlinepayoff}{}{%
    \usebeamerfont{footline}\hfill\@footlinepayoff
  }
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\makeatother

\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! It works. Another way is change the "\TikzSplitSlide" command.